# How do working with regular images and images for buttons differ in `ios`?

Tags: ios, image

I'm struggling with understanding how images and their different sizes/resolutions work in `ios` development.

Do images that will be used for buttons always have to be squares (like App Icons)? and are there specific dimensions that they would need to have?

Also generally speaking, how should images that would be used for buttons be sized in the `Assets.xcassets` folder as compared to Images that would be shown as regular images? (that is if there is a difference)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can create buttons of any size you like there is no difference. Your image should match the aspect ratio of the button but it's all entirely up to you.

Sizing in the Assets catalog would be the same as any other image with 1x, 2x and 3x variations.

Try it out in Storyboard and you will see immediate results.